# How to generate tile of artical automatically in drupal?

Tags: drupal-7

There are several fields and I want generate title from these fields by concatenating them by character '||' in an article  in Drupal. However I find it that you must input article title  manually, then how to generate title automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [Auto Node Title](https://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) in a project for my client and worked fine to generate titles automatically for the nodes. I don't know if with it you can generate title for the other fields also, but maybe with some additional configuration it would be possible to do